# multiple process in single set up using C# windows applicarion

Tags: c#, windows, process, installation, setup-project

An installation package file **(.msi)** on a CD or flash drive will be given to the client in order to install the Client Application. The installation file / disk will include the necessary software needed for the application to function, e.g. .Net Framework and SQL Express (including the latest service packs for both), GPRS modem driver software, and the application itself. This will be a simple installation process making it possible for clients to install the application themselves.

the set up of client has first install the .net then sql express then gprs modem driver software and after the appliaction.

I want to write a program in C# to add the multiple process of setup's in a single setup file.

Comment: want to write a  installer where all necessary software are bundle.

Comment: If you want, you can write it. But I'm afraid you can't do it in C# because .Net framework must already be installed so that users could run a single file to install everything in one step. You can write a simple batch file which will run setups in the correct order; and installers could be started in silent mode.

Comment: i am new in batch .will you plz show me some syntax or any example how to using the batch file  to execute setup softwares in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure why you would want to write one in C# youself. Have a look at [wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) especially the [bundle tutorial](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch to start all your .exe files one after the other and give the path of the batch to run on start of the cd. This way you will not have to write a C# code for everything. Just maintain the order in which you want to install the softwares. Hope this helps!!!